# JSON parse error: unrecognised token <

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, react-native

I am trying to implement user registration in my app. I used node.js express to create my backend and passed a insert query in a .js file i created in the router folder. I have added all the necessary things in app.js too.

Following is my backend code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database:'MobileDB',
})

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

        var name = req.body.name;
        var email = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var phone = req.body.phone;
        connection.query("INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `phone`) VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', '')",[null,name,username,password,phone],function(err,row,fields){
          if (err) console.log(err);

          if(row.length > 0){
              res.send({'success': true, 'message': 'welcome new user'});
          } else {
            res.send({'success':false,'message':'user not found, please try again'});
          }
      });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

and The following is my registration page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, List,Thumbnail, ListItem, InputGroup, Input, Icon, Text, Picker, Button,Header,Footer} from 'native-base';
import {
Router,
Actions,
Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
const Item = Picker.Item;
export default class Reg extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name:'',
            username:'',
            password:'',
            phone:'',
            }

        };
    }
      Reg = () => {


            fetch('http://192.168.0.20:3000/reg', {
             method : 'POST',
                  headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  },

                  body: JSON.stringify({
                  name:this.state.name,
                  username:this.state.username,
                  password:this.state.password,
                  phone:this.state.phone,

                  })
            })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                  if(res.success=== true){
                  var username = res.message;

                     AsyncStorage.setItem('username', username);
                     Actions.Ideas();}
                     else {
                    alert(res.message);
                }



            })

            .done();

      }
    render(){
      return(
      <Container>
            <Content>
                    <View style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
                    <Button transparent onPress={Actions.upload}>
                    <Icon name='ios-contact' style={{fontSize:30}}/>
                    </Button>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{top:20}}>
                    <List>
                        <ListItem>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Icon name="ios-person-outline" style={{ color: '#5bc0de' }} />
                                <Input onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}
                                  value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name" />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Icon name="ios-at-outline" style={{color:'#5bc0de'}}/>
                                <Input onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                                   value={this.state.username} placeholder="Email" />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Icon name="ios-lock-outline" style={{ color: '#5bc0de' }} />
                                <Input onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                                 value={this.state.password}placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Icon name="ios-call-outline" style={{ color: '#5bc0de' }} />
                                <Input onChangeText={(phone) => this.setState({phone})}
                                 value={this.state.phone}placeholder="Phone" keyboardType="numeric" />
                            </InputGroup>
                        </ListItem>

                    </List>
                    <Button info style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop:20, marginBottom: 20 }} onPress={this.Reg}>
                        SIGN UP
                    </Button>
                    </View>
                </Content>
            </Container>

        );
    }
}
```

When i click on the SignUp button it shows unrecognised token error. I can't figure out where i went wrong. Please help.

Comment: print 'response' from promise

Comment: i don't understand.

Comment: http://192.168.0.20:3000/  this IP is your local machine IP or globe IP  ?

Comment: @ArunkumarRamaraj local machine IP

Comment: It worked fine for login. But i don't know why it isn't working for registration.

Comment: Try this IP http://10.0.2.2:3000

Comment: not working @10.0.2.2

Comment: Can you use postman to verify your server response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach Chrome debugger and enable pause on exceptions, you will get to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Reg()` function, `'http://192.168.0.20:3000/reg'` should be `'http://192.168.0.20:3000/'` I believe.

I think you're getting back some unwanted HTML with your current code. I assume its because you're attempting to send a POST request to an undefined route.

Right before your `if` statement, console.log the response `res` so you know exactly what you're getting back from your backend.

Comment: and i am not getting any thing. when console.log. It just goes straight to the error screen.

Comment: This might not make a difference but capitalize the T in Content-Type in the headers section of the request.

Comment: Also your route is defined as `/` not `/reg`

Comment: Do you know how to debug remotely using chrome tools?

Comment: what are you using to run the app? xcode? android studios?

Comment: on your emulator press `command D` then select "Debug JS Remotely" 
This will open up a tab in chrome. On that page in chrome, right click and select `inspect page.` This will open up the developer tools. From there look at the top nav and select console. Now you can console.log from your react-native app and you will see it even if you get the Red Screen of death on the Emulator.

Comment: Once you do that, go back and console.log the `res` right before your `if` statement

Comment: after that? how do i fix the errors that i showing.

Comment: What you console.log will help you narrow down where the problem is. Were you able to log the response in the Chrome tools? If so, What did it say? It should have more details than just "unexpected <"

Comment: yes it said unexpected token < in JSON at position 0